# Number of Items in a list not in increasing order

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
def num_not_increasing(L)"""
    number of pairs in L that are not in increasing order. 
    switches([6, 1, 4]) returns 2, since (6, 1) and (6, 4) are out of order.
    """
```

I can do this easily using two while loops and indexing through, but how can I achieve this recursively in python?

edit: what i acheived with while loops:

```
def switches(L):
if len(L) < 2:
    return 0
else:
    i = 0
    j = 1
    count = 0
    while i  < len(L)-1:
        while j <len(L):
            if L[i] > L[j]:
                count+=1
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return count
```

Comment: Why recursively? It's not your best option here.

Comment: Recursively because i'm doing a list of problems to review recursive problem solving for exams and this is one of the problems im stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting this?

```
def COUNT(ind, prev, L):
    if(ind>=len(L)):
        return 0

    val = 0   

    val += COUNT(ind+1, prev, L)

    if(L[ind]<=L[prev]):
        val = val+1

    return val


def num_not_increasing(lst):
    val = 0
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        val += COUNT(i+1, i, lst)
    return val

L = [6,1,5,4,2]

print num_not_increasing(L)
```